# stop a running mcparallel job prematurely

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have three tasks:

1. is disk I/O bound
2. is network I/O bound
3. is CPU bound on a remote machine

The result of 3 will tell me whether the answer I want will come from task 1 or task 2.  Since each task requires separate resources, I'd like to start all three tasks with mcparallel, then wait on the result from the third task and determine whether to terminate task 1 or task 2.  However, I can not determine how to prematurely cancel an mcparallel task from within R.  Is it safe to just kill the PID of the forked process from a call to system()?  If not, is there a better way to cancel the unneeded computation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think the `parallel` package supports an official way to kill a process started via `mcparallel`, but my guess is that it's safe to do, and you can use the `pskill` function from the `tools` package to do it. Here's an example:

```
library(parallel)
library(tools)

fun1 <- function() {Sys.sleep(20); 1}
fun2 <- function() {Sys.sleep(20); 2}
fun3 <- function() {Sys.sleep(5); sample(2, 1)}
f1 <- mcparallel(fun1())
f2 <- mcparallel(fun2())
f3 <- mcparallel(fun3())
r <- mccollect(f3)
if (r[[1]] == 1) {
  cat('killing fun1...\n')
  pskill(f1$pid)
  print(mccollect(f1))
  r <- mccollect(f2)
} else {
  cat('killing fun2...\n')
  pskill(f2$pid)
  print(mccollect(f2))
  r <- mccollect(f1)
}
print(r)
```

It's usually dangerous to randomly kill threads within a multi-threaded application because they might be holding a shared lock of some kind, but these of course are processes, and the master process seems to handle the situation just fine.

Comment: Seems straightforward, I've now tried this a couple times and killing the parallel pid seemed to have no untoward side effects.  +1 for pskill in tools.

Answer (score 0):

current version of parallel::mccollect() supports `wait` argument.

Simply pass FALSE to quit any running jobs prematurely.

```
> mccollect(wait = FALSE)
```